# Add floats found in single string

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have started using financial spreadsheets and am looking for a way to extract float (price) numbers from multi-line strings. Attached is an example of how I format my prices and totals by category:

example of spreadsheet format[image]

As you can see, I am manually inputting the totals found within the parentheses in order to sum them, but it takes a long time and there is margin for error.

I am looking for EITHER an app scripts or formula solution which will extract float numbers--or numbers contained within parentheses--from a single string and total them.

TIA!

I tried using google app scripts with the following method

```
function addPricesFoundWithinCell(input) {
  var regExp = /(?:\()[^\(\)]*?(?:\))/g;
  var matches = regExp.exec(input);
  const initialValue = 0;
  return matches.reduce(
  (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue,
  initialValue,
);
}
```

it did not work! I am not so familiar with javascript

Comment: You can try: `=sum(split(A1,"()"))` (*provided item_name itself is not a complete number*)

Comment: Congrats on new privileges!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your function like this:

```js
function addPricesFoundWithinCell(input) {
  return (input.match(/\(\d*\.?\d+\)/g) || [])
  .reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev + +curr.replace(/^\(|\)$/g, '');
  }, 0);
}
```

The `\(\d*\.?\d+\)` regex matches integer or float numbers inside parentheses, these parentheses will be removed later when summing up the numbers, see `curr.replace(/^\(|\)$/g, '')`.

Alternatively, you can try using `matchAll` with your regex, but you will need to use `Array.from`:

```js
function addPricesFoundWithinCell(input) {
  return (Array.from(input.matchAll(/\((\d*\.?\d+)\)/g), x=>x[1]) || [])
  .reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev + +curr;
  }, 0);
}
```

With `Array.from(input.matchAll(/\((\d*\.?\d+)\)/g), x=>x[1])`, you only get Group 1 content from the matches.

Comment: Thank you so much! Regex is alien to me haha. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cpp
=SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\b[\d.]+\b)|.","$1"),CHAR(10)))
```

[image]